# PG restore breaking with parallel import and SSL Error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I've been using the exact same restore script to restore a dumped PostgreSQL database for the past 6 months that just decided to break.

I am getting the following error

`pg_restore: [archiver (db)] error returned by PQputCopyData: SSL error: tlsv1 alert protocol version`
`pg_restore: [parallel archiver] a worker process died unexpectedly`

The command used is relatively basic and nothing has changed, it just does not work anymore.

The script:

`pg_restore --clean -v -h amazonaws.com -j 4 -U username -d database_name C:\Users\dump.dir`

Does anyone have any idea as to why this error is occurring?

Note: I am dumping a local database and restoring said database to AWS using a local machine.

Comment: Please check the database server logs. There should be a message about what caused the client to get killed.

Comment: It seems to be complaining about TLS protocol versions. Has something changed in your networking setup, or could your version of pg_restore be very old?